# how to create a table with acm

Tags: tables, errors, tabulary

I am creatin a table with latex using ACM template with `\documentclass[sigconf, anonymous]{acmart}`
This is my code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{CLCL}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Security} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Data protection} \\\cmidrule(rl){1-2}\cmidrule(rl){3-4}
Level & \hfil Mode & Encryption & \hfil Authenticity\\
%\midrule
\cmidrule(rl){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}\cmidrule(rl){3-3}\cmidrule(rl){4-4}
  0 & No Security     & No  &  Not validated   \\
  1 & AES-CBC-MAC-32  & No  &  32-bit MIC \\   
  2 & AES-CBC-MAC-64  & No  &  64-bit MIC   \\   
  3 & AES-CBC-MAC-128 & No  &  128-bit MIC  \\   
  4 & AES-CTR         & Yes &  Not validated       \\   
  5 & AES-CCM-32      & Yes &  32-bit MIC     \\   
  6 & AES-CCM-64      & Yes &  64-bit MIC     \\   
  7 & AES-CCM-128     & Yes &  128-bit MIC    \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
```

Initially, with IEEE template I got:

[image]

but with the ACM, I got this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The ACM provides several LaTeX document classes. Please be more specific as to which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico could  please see the edited question?

Comment: Thanks for providing the additional piece of information. I'm afraid I cannot reproduce the issue you're experiening, i.e., the table looks exactly like one would expect. Please tell us more about which packages (other than `tabulary` and `booktabs`) you load in the document's preamble.

Comment: @Mico you got 1 out of 2 right:-)

Comment: Just replace `\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{CLCL}` into `\begin{tabular}{clcl}` and `\end{tabulary}` with `\end{tabular}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I must confess that it hadn't occurred to me that the OP (a) might not be loading the `tabulary` package and (b) might be ignoring a fairly self-explanatory error message...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

If you get a TeX error then you should not even look at the PDF, look at the log, your log will show

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment tabulary undefined.
```

as `tabulary` is not defined. (You must have loaded `booktabs` though otherwise the output would not have the horizontal rules).

You need

```
\usepackage{tabulary}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{CLCL}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Security} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Data protection} \\\cmidrule(rl){1-2}\cmidrule(rl){3-4}
Level & \hfil Mode & Encryption & \hfil Authenticity\\
%\midrule
\cmidrule(rl){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}\cmidrule(rl){3-3}\cmidrule(rl){4-4}
  0 & No Security     & No  &  Not validated   \\
  1 & AES-CBC-MAC-32  & No  &  32-bit MIC \\   
  2 & AES-CBC-MAC-64  & No  &  64-bit MIC   \\   
  3 & AES-CBC-MAC-128 & No  &  128-bit MIC  \\   
  4 & AES-CTR         & Yes &  Not validated       \\   
  5 & AES-CCM-32      & Yes &  32-bit MIC     \\   
  6 & AES-CCM-64      & Yes &  64-bit MIC     \\   
  7 & AES-CCM-128     & Yes &  128-bit MIC    \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Zarko the posted code is the source of the posted image, it answesr the OPs question "Why do I get this weird output" showing that it is not as the OP guessed due to the `acm` class, but can be obtained from `article` if as shown you ignore errors and don't load needed packages.